# How to work with a an Future which wrappes an Either?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, future, either

In my current project, I used `Either[Result, HandbookModule]` (`Result` is an HTTP Statuscode) as a return type so that I can create the correct status when something goes wrong. I have now refactored my database access to be non-blocking.

This change requires that my return type for database access functions changed to `Future[Either[Result, HandbookModule]]`.

Now I am not sure on how to glue this function together with another function which returns `Either[Result, Long]`.

So to better illustrate what I mean:

```scala
def moduleDao.getHandbooks(offset, limit): Future[Either[Result, List[Module]] = Future(Right(List(Module(1))))

def nextOffset(offset, limit, results): Either[_, Long] = Right(1)

def getHandbooks(
  offset: Long,
  limit: Long): Future[Either[Result, (List[HandbookModule], Long)]] = {
  for {
    results <- moduleDao.getHandbooks(offset, limit)
    offset  <- nextOffset(offset, limit, results)
  } yield (results, offset)
}
```

Before the change, this was obviously no problem but I don't know what would be the best approach.

Or is there a way to convert a `Future[Either[A, B]]` to an `Either[A, Future[B]]`?

Comment: Why do you need to change it? Why not just on case it is valid compute the future?

Comment: In the example i provided this would work but i have also some more complex cases.

Comment: Try to create a [mcve] of your complex case, it will be easier to help you this way.

Comment: okay i added a more complex example. Hope it is usable

Comment: Your example doesn't compile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to unwrap your method from the Future, you'd have to block it and wait for the result. You could do it using `Await.result`.

But blocking the future is usually not considered to be the best practice. More on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18714627/why-blocking-on-future-considered-a-bad-practice/18715301).

So you should tackle that problem differently. What you're facing is actually common issue with nested monad stacks and it can be handled with monad transformers.

Scala's functional programming library [cats](https://typelevel.org/cats/) provides an implementation of [EitherT](https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/eithert.html) monad transformer.

In your case, you could use `EitherT.apply` to transform `Future[Either[Result, List[Module]]` into `EitherT[Future, Result, List[Module]]` and `EitherT.fromEither` to lift `Either[_, Long]`.

It could look like this:

```
import cats.data.EitherT
import cats.implicits._
  
def getHandbooks(
   offset: Long,
   limit: Long
): Future[Either[String, (List[String], Long)]] = {
  val result: EitherT[Future, String, (List[String], Long)] = for {
    results <- EitherT(moduleDao.getHandbooks(offset, limit))
    offset  <- EitherT.fromEither[Future](nextOffset(offset, limit, results))
  } yield (results, offset)

  result.value //unwrap result from EitherT
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had to make a number of assumptions and adjustments/corrections to the posted code in order to make it usable. (You don't make it easy for those who want to help you.)

If you can tolerate a default `Long` value, when `nextOffset()` returns `Left` instead of `Right[Long]`, then this appears to type-check and compile.

```
def getHandbooks(offset: Long
                ,limit : Long
                ): Future[Either[Result, (List[Module], Long)]] =
  moduleDao.getHandbooks(offset,limit).map(_.map(ms => 
    (ms, nextOffset(offset,limit,ms).getOrElse(0L))))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the `Left` side of you `Either` represents the error state, correct?

If so, I think you should refactor your API to not use `Either`, and simply use a failed `Future` to represent the error state. Something along the lines of:

```
// Custom exception that wraps existing Result
case class MyCustomException(result: Result) extends Exception

class ModuleDao {
  ...
  def getHandbooks(offset, limit): Future[List[Module] = {
    // You'd probably want to do this asynchronously
    // But for demonstration purposes
    val origRetVal: Either[Result, List[Module] = ??? // current code returning your Either
    origRetVal match {
      case Right(modules: List[Module]) =>
        Future.successful(modules)
      case Left(result: Result) =>
        // Failed future wrapping custom exception
        Future.failed(MyCustomException(result))
    }
  }
  ...
}
```